# Java interfaces and downcasting

Tags: java, interface

I have a `Fraction` class which implements an interface named `FractionInterface`. In `FractionInterface` I have specified a method `FractionInterface add(FractionInterface secondFraction);`. I am having trouble implementing this method in my `Fraction` class.

```
public class Fraction implements FractionInterface
{private int num; // Numerator 
private int den; // Denominator
    public int getNum()
{
    return this.num;
}   // end getNum

public int getDen()
{
    return this.den;
}   // end getDen
public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface secondFraction)
    {
     FractionInterface result = (num*secondFraction.getDen()+secondFraction.getNum()*den)/
     (den*secondFraction.getDen());
    }
}
```

I get an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to FractionInterface.", I was given a hint to downcast the parameter secondFraction from FractionInterface to Fraction but i'm not sure how to do that. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just provide `valueOf(int i)` and `toInt()` methods

Comment: I haven't learned about that yet and don't think I am allowed to use those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect this to do?

```
FractionInterface result = (num*secondFraction.getDen()+secondFraction.getNum()*den)/
 (den*secondFraction.getDen());
```

The right side is a number, the left side is an object. The compiler has no way to know how to convert a number into a `Fraction` object.

You need a constructor in your `Fraction` class that accepts a numerator and denominator:

```
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)  {
   num = numerator;
   den = denominator;
}
```

and then do this

```
FractionInterface result = new Fraction(THENUMERATOR, THEDEMONIMATOR);
```

which I think, for you, is

```
FractionInterface result = new Fraction(
   (num*secondFraction.getDen()+secondFraction.getNum()*den),
   (den*secondFraction.getDen());
```

Comment: The type FractionInterface can be of type Fraction because Fraction implements FractionInterface right?

Comment: "Can be"? A `Fraction` implements `FractionInterface`, and therefore ***is*** a `FractionInterface`.